# Show that if $f,g:\Bbb{N}\to \Bbb{C}$ are multiplicative, then so is $f*g(n)=\sum_{d|n}{f(d)g({n\over d})}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that if $f,g:\Bbb{N}\to \Bbb{C}$ are multiplicative, then so is $f*g(n)=\sum_{d|n}{f(d)g({n\over d})}$.

What I did is: Let $m$ and $n$ be co-primes. $m's$ divisors=$\{1,m_1,...,m_s,m\}$, $n's$ divisors=$\{1,n_1,...,n_r,n\}$, therefore:

$f*g(mn)=f(1)g(mn)+f(m_1)g({mn\over m_1})+...+f(m_s)g({mn\over m_s})+f(m)g({n})+f(n_1)g({mn\over n_1})+...+f(n_r)g({mn\over n_r})+f(n)g({m})$.

Denoting ${m\over m_i}=m_i'$ and given $f,g$ are multiplicative: 
$f*g(mn)=f(1)g(m)g(n)+f(m_1)g(m_1')g(n)+...+f(m_1)g(m_s')g(n)+f(m)g({n})+f(n_1)g(n_1')g(m)+...+f(n_r)g(n_r')g(m)+f(n)g({m})$.

Now, the problem is when I try to calculate $(f*g(m))\cdot (f*g(n))$: there are many factors of which I can't get rid!

I would appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: I believe there are some summands missing in your calculation of  $(f * g)(mn)$. Note that $m_i n_j$ is a divisor of $mn$ for all $i$ and $j$.

Comment: You are correct!
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$h\left(n\right):=\sum_{d\mid n}f\left(d\right)g\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)=\sum_{d_{1}d_{2}=n}f\left(d_{1}\right)g\left(d_{2}\right)
 $$ then if $ \left(m,n\right)=1
 $ $$h\left(nm\right)=\sum_{d\mid mn}f\left(d\right)g\left(\frac{mn}{d}\right)=\sum_{d_{1}\mid n,\, d_{2}\mid m}f\left(d_{1}d_{2}\right)g\left(\frac{n}{d_{1}}\frac{m}{d_{2}}\right)=\sum_{d_{1}\mid n}f\left(d_{1}\right)g\left(\frac{n}{d_{1}}\right)\sum_{d_{2}\mid m}f\left(d_{2}\right)g\left(\frac{m}{d_{2}}\right)=h\left(n\right)h\left(m\right).
 $$ (note that $\left(d_{1},d_{2}\right)=1
 $).

Comment: This is where I was mistaken. Thank you!

Comment: @Meitar You're welcome.